# Как группе выдать права доступа к папке в Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, права, chmod

У меня имеются 2 пользователя: usr1 и usr2

```
Выполняя команду: id usr1
Мы получаем: uid=1(usr1) gid=1(usr1) groups=1(usr1),3(groups_test)

Выполняя команду: id usr2
Мы получаем: uid=2(usr2) gid=2(usr2) groups=2(usr2),3(groups_test)
```

Видно, что пользователи состоят в одной группе "groups_test".

Есть папке "Data" владельцем которой является usr1, я поставил данной папке права "775", владелец может делать все, групповые права доступны все и публичные только на чтении и выполнение. Почему usr2 не может изменять, переименовывать файлы в папке "Data", если групповые права доступны все и usr2 находится в одной группе с владельцем файла? Помогите исправить, уже перерыл кучу мануалов.

**UPD:**

```
Выполняя команду: getfacl Data
Мы получаем: 
# file: Data
# owner: usr1
# group: usr1
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

Comment: У папки Data покажите все права, собственника и группу.  можно ещё и так : `$ getfacl Data`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe , сделал и добавил ответ выше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поменять группу директории нужно:

`chgrp groups_test Data`

Изменять чужие файлы `usr2` может только если данный файл состоит в группе `groups_test`. Право записи на директорию позволяет только добавлять файлы и удалять.

Чтобы все новые файлы имели автоматически группу `groups_test` нужно ещё подправить данную папку так:

`chmod g+s Data`